What should I change in this Kaiju to allow it to play basketball
There's a Kaiju lets name him Jerry. Jerry loves basketball with him always watching NBA games on massive screens however due to his anatomy as a Kaiju he is unable to play the sport. Jerry gets some giant engineers to create the ball and net necessary for the sport. However Jerry himself is unable to play basketball. However Jerry remembers that he has the ability to shape shift into anything. However, Jerry does not know what changes he needs to make to himself so that he can play the sport of basketball. Can you guys help him out and tell him what he needs to play basketball?

Jerry in his base form resembles a 300 meter tall T-Rex.
Jerry has the ability to turn off the square cube law fir any object in a km range including himself
Jerry has Kaiju friends he can play basketball with and apply his shape shifting to.
Jerry can incorporate any material or design into his body as long as the material/design does not exist.
The main problem jerry has is bouncing the ball and moving his body fast enough to block, shoot, and dribble.


Kaiju do not obey the square-cube law. If Jerry himself is subject to the square-cube law, he can't be a 300m tall T-rex. He'd weigh over a million tons, and his legs would snap like toothpicks. This is a non-starter, none of these huge creatures are playing basketball while subject to the square-cube law. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167568/would-an-anti-gravity-organ-allow-kaiju-to-avoid-cube-square-problems

Jerry has the ability to turn off the square cube law for objects near him but he lacks the ability to turn it off for himself => Jerry doesn't exist

Ain't no rule says a kaiju can't play basketball.


Jerry remembers that he has the ability to shape shift into anything. However, Jerry does not know what changes he needs to make to himself so that he can play the sport of basketball.

Jerry needs to stop watching games on massive screens and go watch a real game with 3D people whose anatomy he can study.
Armed with an understanding of human anatomy Jerry realizes that the fundamental problem is being 300m tall. Jerry aims for 2m.
Attempts to shrink down may be complicated by pesky rules such as conservation of mass. Pouting over this issue during half time, Jerry notices a kid playing with a tiny toy skateboard. The kid is pretending that his fingers are his legs and is doing skateboarding tricks while still sitting in his seat.
Inspired, Jerry leaves the bulk of his mass in the parking lot and sends a 2m tall part of himself (that looks suspiciously like Michael Jordan) onto the court. Few notice the tiny tendril that links back to the bulk of Jerry's mass.
Unfortunately, rather than giving Jerry the chance to play basketball this gets him mobbed by fans.

This, but since Jerry can include any design in his body, he can include a radio transmitter and receiver and doesn't need a "land line" tendril.

@gs true, but that would require routing all bodily control functions through a limited wireless connection, as well as developing a method to convert neural signals to and from radio-transmissible data.

I was about to comment to the question that Jerry must be pretty dense not to simply change shape into one of the players he was watching when I noticed your answer. +1!

Frame Challenge
American Football traces its lineage to Rugby, Basketball and Netball are related, Ice Hockey has ties to Lacrosse etc.
Jerry and his friends attempt to play a form of Basketball, but due to their different anatomical forms, the game evolves and morphs into a new game (just how Netball was based on a teachers misunderstanding of a description of Basketball) and a new sport is created:
KaijuBall
Edit:
Eventually, Kaiju ball gets picked up by a local news station - fans are drawn to the spectacle of super-sized entities moving around and the sheer impact of the sport.
A League is formed, Jerry goes Pro - and then ESPN picks it up and the sport goes international.
Jerry eventually retires, takes a seat on the board of directors for the NKA - until a fatefull scandal forces him to step down.

Ugh, the NKA isn't even formed yet and cancel culture is already gunning for poor Jerry.

We are each masters of our own bodies
We spend our whole lives learning to walk, run, throw, etc. using the bodies that we are in.  Change one thing, and all of your muscle memory is off.  This is especially true for things that take precise timing like throwing a ball into a small hoop; so, even if a humanoid body plan might be better for playing basketball than than a giant Kaiju body plan in theory, that does not mean that Jerry will play better as a humanoid than as Kaiju.
Another key aspect of your setting is that Jerry wants to play with his Kaiju friends.  This means that they will each have the same advantages and handicaps as Jerry; so, even if certain things are a bit harder or easier because of their Kaiju body plan, it will all be fair as long as they play with the same handicaps, and ultimately, fairness is more important than optimization.  This may mean that Jerry may need to put the hoop a bit lower compared to his body if he struggles to turn his shoulders enough, and he may need to come up with his own plays that account for the space that his long tail and large head take up, but that's will do more to add flavor to your setting than to take it away; so, I'd advocate for playing it up.
Besides, at the end of the day, this is just so much better than boring old human basketball: https://youtube.com/shorts/gQ3nQ7A_wIo?si=zPnca9O-j88zsqhs
